# Enumerative combinatorics. Number of unique сhords

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

Have:

- Circle
- N * 2 equidistant points on circle
- N chords connecting points into pairs
- Exactly 1 chord connected to each points

Additional conditions:

- Points are equivalent, so a1a2 = a2a1, aabbccdd = aaccbbdd
- Circle can be rotated (excluding rotated copies of sequences), so aabbcc = caabbc
- Circle can be mirrored (excluding mirror copies), so aabcbc = cbcbaa

Question is:

- How many unique patterns P can be created for given N?

As I found, the problem refers to [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) with Necklaces and bracelets.
But I don't know how to exclude patterns by additional conditions (especially by mirroring and swaping colors)

I manual-calculated soultions for N = 1, 2, 3, 4

N = 1, P = 1

N = 2, P = 2

N = 3, P = 5

N = 4, P = 17

Also I prepared visual representation of solutions for N = 1, 2, 3

1, 2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2PqP.png

3 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/phOaK.png

Any suggestions for solution by single forumla?
Is this correct collection? https://oeis.org/A054499

(Im novice level at combinatorics, so each step and solution I need to be re-checked and validated)

Comment: The title of OEIS A054499 does indeed seem to match your description and small examples

Comment: The bibliography at the link is extensive. The generalization to three instances each, four instances etc. does not appear to be in the OEIS yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to start by saying that OP has a good question that shows
that effort was put into presentation and content. Note first that the
OEIS says that this  material is from a Ph.D. thesis by  R. Read so we
cannot hope for easy answers, also the formulae given by the OEIS look
formidable. **Note to  the reader.** The formulae for the  case of two
instances   of   $n$   colors   each   that   are   given   at   [OEIS
A054499](https://oeis.org/A054499)  will  produce  an  instant  answer
using negligable computational resources.  Hence the reader is invited
to  study the  cited  papers  and we  will  not  discuss this  problem
here. We consider  a generalization instead, namely to  three, four or
five instances of $n$ swappable colors. Let the parameter $k$ give the
number of instances of each color. Here we have $k=3,4,5.$

The OP  made good initial progress  by noting that we  might apply the
**Polya Enumeration  Theorem** (PET) but  here we need  something more
general, which  is **Power Group  Enumeration** (PGE) as  described by
Harary and Palmer in their classic text *Graphical Enumeration* and by
Fripertinger in his paper *Enumeration in Musical Theory.* PET is when
we  have objects  with a  generating function  being distributed  into
slots while PGE also has a group  acting on the objects, i.e. we count
orbits with objects  being distributed into slots  where a permutation
group  permutes the  slots and  another the  objects. This  is a  very
simple algorithm where we just  need to insert the corresponding cycle
indices into  the appropriate place and  are ready to go.  We need the
cycle index of  the slot permutation group and the  cycle index of the
object permutation group. Here we have  $kn$ slots that receive one of
$n$ types  of labels or colors,  with $k$ instances of  each color and
the symmetric group acting on  the colors. *The slot permutation group
is  the  dihedral  group  on   $kn$  slots  $D_{kn}$  and  the  object
permutation group is the symmetric group  $S_n.$* The heart of the PGE
algorithm is to compute the number of orbits by Burnside's lemma which
says to average the number of assignments fixed by the elements of the
power group.  But  this number is easy to compute.   Suppose we have a
permutation $\alpha$  from the slot  permutation group $D_{kn}$  and a
permutation $\beta$ from $S_n$.  If we place the appropriate number of
complete, directed and consecutive copies of a cycle from $\beta$ on a
cycle  from $\alpha$  then this  assignment is  fixed under  the power
group  action for  $(\alpha,\beta)$ ,  and  this is  possible iff  the
length of the cycle from $\beta$  divides the length of the cycle from
$\alpha$ .   The process yields as  many assignments as the  length of
the cycle from $\beta$.  The problem here is that it is not sufficient
to count the assignments, we also  need to classify them by the number
of instances of  each color that appear in the  assignment, so that we
may subsequently  filter out  the ones  where each  of the  $n$ colors
appears $k$ times.   Hence we need a generating function  and we track
how many  instances of each color  have been placed when  covering the
cycles  of $\alpha.$  This  will  produce a  product  of  sums in  the
variables  $A_1$ to  $A_n$ of  the generating  function where  the sum
terms represent a single covering of  a single cycle from $\alpha$ and
the  variables represent  the colors.   Once  all of  these have  been
collected  for the  pair  we  may extract  the  coefficient on  $A_1^k
\times\cdots\times  A_n^k$ by  sequentially differentiating  $k$ times
with respect to the variables and  evaluating with the variable set to
zero. We keep it compact  by differentiating rather than expanding the
product, which would produce an exponential number of terms.  With the
object  permutation group  being  the symmetric  group the  generating
function  corresponding to  the  cycles from  $\beta$  is obtained  by
constructing  a representative  in the  $n$ variables  for the  colors
whose factorization into cycles is $\beta$.

For the two cycle indices we have the usual index for the dihedral group
starting from the cyclic group where we have

$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

and

$$Z(D_n) = 
\frac{1}{2} Z(C_n) +
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2^{(n-1)/2} & n \text{ odd} \\
\frac{1}{4} \left( a_1^2 a_2^{n/2-1} + a_2^{n/2} \right)
& n \text{ even.}
\end{cases}$$

For the object permutation group there is the recurrence by Lovasz for
the cycle index $Z(S_n)$, which is

$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{\ell=1}^n  a_\ell Z(S_{n-\ell})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

With these  two cycle indices we  are ready to run  the PGE algorithm,
iterating over  pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$  and collecting  the respective
contributions. The  code below shows  how to implement this,  which is
extremely    straightforward,    requiring    no    additional    data
structures. There are some minor tweaks such as that we cannot cover a
cycle from $\alpha$ with more than  $k$ copies of a cycle from $\beta$
as  we cannot  use  a variable  more  than $k$  times.  We obtain  the
sequence for the number of chord diagrams:

$$1, 2, 5, 17, 79, 554, 5283, 65346, 966156, 16411700, 312700297,
\\ 6589356711, 152041845075, 3811786161002, 103171594789775, \ldots$$

which points  to [OEIS A054499](https://oeis.org/A054499) as  noted by
OP.  Here is the value for $n=42$

$$3192542278675493533067925669542823243829694232124271825606504.$$

As  we can  see these  values  match the  OEIS data,  which shows  the
algorithm is working.  Here is the sequence for  three instances which
is now at [OEIS A362657](https://oeis.org/A362657):

$$1, 1, 3, 25, 713, 47283, 5301453, 862284559,
\\ 190869905951, 55139769554236, \ldots$$

Four instances is at [OEIS A362658](https://oeis.org/A362658):

$$1, 1, 7, 297, 83488, 63698215, 93945180662,
235528677557853, \ldots$$

Five instances is at [OEIS A362659](https://oeis.org/A362659):

$$1, 1, 13, 4378, 12233517, 103894521686, 2056311437607449,
\\ 81740134830144396361, \ldots$$

This was the code:

```
with(combinat); with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d;

    add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n))/n;
end;

pet_cycleind_dihedral :=
proc(n)
local s;

    s := 1/2*pet_cycleind_cyclic(n);

    if(type(n, odd)) then
        s := s + 1/2*a[1]*a[2]^((n-1)/2);
    else
        s := s + 1/4*(a[1]^2*a[2]^((n-2)/2) + a[2]^(n/2));
    fi;

    s;
end;


pet_prod2vrep :=
proc(varp)
    local v, d, q, res, len, cyc, p;

    q := 1; res := [];

    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        len := op(1, v);

        for cyc to d do
            res :=
            [op(res), mul(A[p], p=q..q+len-1)];
            q := q+len;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

BRACL_CONTRIB :=
proc(gf, n, k)
local q, contr;

    contr := gf;
    for q to n do
        contr := diff(contr, A[q]$k);
        contr := 1/k!*subs(A[q]=0, contr);
    od;

    contr;
end;

BRACL :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_colors, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, cyc_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q, rep;

    if n = 0 or n = 1 then return 1 fi;

    idx_slots := pet_cycleind_dihedral(k*n);
    idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(n);

    res := 0;

    for term_b in idx_colors do
        rep := pet_prod2vrep(term_b);

        for term_a in idx_slots do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for cyc_b in rep do
                    len_b := nops(cyc_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        if len_a/len_b <= k then
                            q := q + len_b*cyc_b^(len_a/len_b);
                        fi;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)
            *BRACL_CONTRIB(p, n, k);
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```