# Redfield-Polya enumeration, but the colors don't matter

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-actions, coloring, polya-counting-theory

Is there a version of Redfield-Polya enumeration with the added condition that you don't care which color is which? An illustrative example is: Count edge-colorings of $K_4$ modulo the group action of graph isomorphism *and* permutation of the colors.

I don't believe this is as simple as quotienting out by permuting colors with the same number of edges. For example, the graph with a red 3-star and a blue triangle and the graph with a blue 3-star and a red triangle are distinct in standard Polya enumeration but we want to drop one of them. Meanwhile, the graph with a red 3-path and a blue 3-path are already considered equivalent by Polya enumeration. So, we have to account for color relabelings that are already induced by graph isomorphisms!

Any references you know of would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The same theorem, but your group is different. Now you have the cartesian product of the group of automorphisms and the group of permutations of colors.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm still not sure how to implement this. In the Wikipedia statement, the group acts on the set X and the colors are the set Y. How would this work once Y is also being acted on by the group? How to define the generating function for colors?

Answer (score 2):

By way of  enrichment this can also be  done using *Power
Group Enumeration*.  As this  algorithm has appeared here
many times  I will just  give one reference to  this [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687456/).

It remains to compute the  two cycle indices, one for the
action  of the  symmetric  group on  the  edges of  $K_n$
(slots) and the symmetric group  $S_m$ on the colors. The
former is a standard computation  and the latter is given
by  the Lovasz  recurrence.  We get  the following  Maple
code:

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_edg :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 or n=1 then return 1; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^((l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1)))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2)))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;

        all := all + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    all;
end;

kn_pge :=
proc(n,m)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_colors, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n = 1 or m = 1 then return 1 fi;

    idx_slots := pet_cycleind_edg(n);
    idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(m);

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_colors do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

We get for at most two colors

$$1, 1, 2, 6, 18, 78, 522, 6178, 137352, \ldots$$

which         points          us         to         [OEIS
A007689](https://oeis.org/A007869)    where    we    find
confirmation of this result.

With at most three colors we find

$$1, 1, 3, 15, 142, 4300, 384199, 98654374, 70130880569,
\ldots$$

With at most four colors we get

$$1, 1, 3, 22, 513, 67685, 37205801, 74992370359,
\\ 543437207831908, \ldots$$

With at most five colors the result is

$$1, 1, 3, 24, 956, 370438, 794610689, 7713545142724,
\\ 334331083961076765, \ldots$$

Observe  that when  we  have $m\gt  n(n-1)/2$ the  answer
stops changeing and becomes independent of $m$ because we
have more  colors than edges  in the graph. With  this we
get the sequence

$$1, 1, 3, 25, 1299, 1974452, 94345468975, 152799292695935115,
\\ 10526127565809458484649781, \ldots$$

This gives  the number  of colorings  of $K_n$  using any
number of swappable colors. We observe that we should get
one  minus this  sequence  when  we have  $m=-1+n(n-1)/2$
colors because with all colors distinct there is just one
such  graph  and  this  is indeed  what  the  Maple  code
produces.

*Important remark.* These sequences  are not in the OEIS,
which is  highly unlikely  and leads  me to  question the
work above.   Therefore we need someone  to independently
verify these numbers.

**Adddendum.** These sequences are in fact in the OEIS I just missed them during my consultation. They are [OEIS A230367](https://oeis.org/A230367), [OEIS A233748](https://oeis.org/A233748), [OEIS A233894](https://oeis.org/A233894), and [OEIS A309116](https://oeis.org/A309116).

Comment: Terrific answer! Surprised and pleased that it got your attention so long after its asking.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the Pólya enumeration theorem to count colorings as equivalent if they agree up to a reassignment of colors: Let $G$ be the automorphism group of the structure and $H$ the symmetric group on the set of colors. Then, the number of colorings up to equivalence is
$$\left.P_G\left(\frac{d}{dz_1}, \frac{d}{dz_2}, \ldots\right) P_H(e^{z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + \cdots}, e^{2(z_2 + z_4 + z_6 + \cdots)}, e^{3(z_3 + z_6 + z_9 + \cdots)}, \ldots)\right\vert_{z_1 = z_2 = \cdots = 0} ,$$
where $P_G$ and $P_H$ are the [cycle index polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) of the action of $G$ and the left action of $H$ on itself. See, e.g., C.L. Liu, *Introduction to Combinatorial Mathematics*, Theorem 5.7.

In our case, $G := \operatorname{Aut}(K_4) \cong S_4$, and it acts faithfully on the set $\mathcal{E}$ of edges, defining an embedding $S_4 \hookrightarrow S_6$. Denote the vertices by $a, b, c, d$ and the edges $ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd$ respectively by $1, \ldots, 6$. Then, $S_4$ is generated by the transposition $(ab)$ and the $4$-cycle $(abcd)$, which correspond respectively to the permutations
$$(24)(35) \quad \textrm{and} \quad (1364) (25) .$$
Computing directly gives that the cycle index polynomial for the action of $G \cong S_4$ on $\mathcal{E}$ is
$$P_G(x_1, \ldots, x_6) = \frac1{24} x_1^6 + \frac38 x_1^2 x_2^2 + \frac14 x_2 x_4 + \frac13 x_3^2 .$$

The symmetric group on a set of $2$ colors is $H \cong C_2$, and its cycle index polynomial is
$$P_H(y_1, y_2) = \frac12 y_1^2 + \frac12 y_2 .$$ So,
$$P_H\left(e^{z_1 + \cdots + z_6}, e^{2 (z_2 + z_4 + z_6)}\right) = \frac12 e^{2 z_1 + \cdots + 2 z_6} + \frac12 e^{2 z_2 + 2 z_4 + 2 z_6}.$$

Assembling the ingredients gives that the number of equivalent colorings is, where we denote $\partial_i := \frac{d}{dz_i}$,
\begin{multline*}
\left.P_G\left(\partial_1, \ldots \partial_6\right) P_H\left(e^{z_1 + \cdots + z_6}, e^{2 (z_2 + z_4 + z_6)}\right)\right\vert_{z_1 = \cdots = z_6 = 0} \\
= \left.\left(\frac1{24} \partial_1^6 + \frac38 \partial_1^2 \partial_2^2 + \frac14 \partial_2 \partial_4 + \frac13 \partial_3^2\right) \left(\frac12 e^{2 z_1 + \cdots + 2 z_6} + \frac12 e^{2 z_2 + 2 z_4 + 2 z_6}\right)\right\vert_{z_1 = \cdots = z_6 = 0} = \color{#bf0000}{\boxed{6}} ,
\end{multline*}
as expected.

Analogous computations gives that up to equivalence there are $18$ edge colorings of $K_5$ and $78$ edge colorings of $K_6$.